# How to reconfigure Oracle 10g xe on Linux

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle10g

I have installed Oracle 10g xe from a deb file on linux, and then started to configure it using this terminal command

> sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure

but after finishing configuration I forgot the password, so how can I reconfigure it again after reinstallation as now when I use the previous command I receive

> Oracle Database 10g Express Edition is already configured

Thanks,

Comment: Excellent tutorial is [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2301639). I guess one can find there solutions for most of the issues with Oracle Express on Linux (specifically Ubuntu).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Oracle creates a system account named oracle. To change password to that account just use

```
passwd oracle
```

if you forgot another password from DB then log in as oracle user and use

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

to change the password for various DB accounts.

To reconfigure change in /etc/default/oracle-xe

```
CONFIGURE_RUN=true
```

to

```
CONFIGURE_RUN=false
```

and rerun

```
sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure
```

Answer (score 23):

Remove `/etc/sysconfig/oracle-xe`
and then `/etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure`

Comment: Worked perfectly with Oracle 11g XE.

Comment: Linux mint (ubuntu I believe as well)
 sudo rm /etc/default/oracle-xe

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 16.04 with Oracle 11g XE. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

For Oracle XE 18c on Oracle Linux (7.7 in this case), the installation can be restarted by executing the following command as `root`:

```
/etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c delete
```

Restart the installation with the same command that was issued initially:

```
/etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c configure
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved...
While removing the oracle I used

> sudo apt-get remove oracle-xe-universal

and then remove the configurations using

> sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/oracle

but these commands don't remove the configurations completely, the solution is to remove the oracle-xe-universal from Synaptic Manager and mark for Complete Removal.

Then install oracle-xe-universal again from the deb file then configure it.

Thanks,

Comment: Is much easier to change /etc/default/oracle-xe :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Oracle XE 18c on Ubuntu), I had to remove the last line from `/etc/oratab`